# How to save PDF from base64 in database with url?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm generating PDF of html table. I want to save pdf in database. This script is downloading pdf. I want to send pdf file to controller side then save in database. I'm getting base64 string in controller now how i can save and retrieve with url?

```
 var doc = new jsPDF({
       unit: 'px',
       format: 'a4'
 });

    doc.fromHTML($('#revision_table').get(0), 2, 2);
    doc.save('scdedule_revision.pdf');
    var pdf = doc.output();

    axios.post(this.$path + 'api/savePdf', null,
           {
              params: {'pdf_file':  doc.output('datauri')}          
           }
    ).then(({data}) => (
           console.log(data)
         ))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Controller:

```
    public function savePdf(Request $request)
{

    $destinationPath = 'users/pdf';
    $fileuploadedpath = '';
    $pdf = $request->get('pdf_file');
    if ($pdf != '') {
        $extension = $pdf->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
        $success[0] = $pdf->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        $fileuploadedpath = url($destinationPath . "/" . $fileName);
    }

    dd($fileuploadedpath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = file_get_contents('string path file');
$content = base64_decode($data);
```

Comment: Tried what to do next? How to save in public_storage?

Comment: rename('file_name_current', ' /storage/public/file_name');

Comment: Why we are using this?

Answer (score 0):

**for storing the base64 into the database you need to simply store the base64 string to database column form controller**

```
  $b64Doc = base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->pdfdoc));
```

**Now for decoding the file use the file all you need to fetch the base64 data form table and then use code below to get the PDF again**

```
// a route is created.
$route    = "pdf/".$name;

// decode base64
$pdf_b64 = base64_decode($base_64);

// you record the file in existing folder
if(file_put_contents($route, $pdf_b64)){

//just to force download by the browser
header("Content-type: application/pdf");

//print base64 decoded
 echo $pdf_b64;
}
```